# Change a javascript function to a jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery to load a page into a div. The page the gets loaded is using a javascript. How can i change the javascript shown below into a jquery

```
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"AdddueBy",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"bDob",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"gDob",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to add jQuery to this? What benefit do you expect it to bring you? (I can see only one possible benefit, but you can get that with about a dozen bytes instead of the many K that jQuery demands)

Comment: @Quentin When the page is called via jquery the javascript will not work. With JQuery it is working fine

Comment: Define "called via jQuery"

Comment: @Quentin lol I may be missunderstanding here as I am relativily new the page is called into a div using submitHandler: function(form) when the page is loaded window.onload does not work but it does work if i use $(document).ready the problem i have now is even though a value is entered into the field when it is posted to another page it says that field is not set but all others are

Answer (score 0):

Besides in jQuery you can use:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // ...
});
```

which can be considered as equivalent of `window.onload` event, but I'd suggest to use [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback instead:

```
$(function() {
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"AdddueBy",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"bDob",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"gDob",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't knew that equivalent for DOM ready. +1

@dfsq why not? what's the difference?

Comment: @dfsq So what? How does it make difference?

Comment: In this case it doesn't make difference, I agree (it was not me who downvoted). But see a guy above will now think that DOM ready is equivalent for window.onload. You should at least note this. Anyway.

Comment: @dfsq TBH it is a weird assumption. Neither `$(window).load()`, nor `$(function() {})` is the equivalent of `window.onload`. Since in both ways jQuery adds the `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` events to `document` and to `window` respectively (except other hidden functionality that supports it). You can see it here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L785. So I don't consider my answer as wrong in any case. If only you and the downvoter understand the word *"equivalent"* in the most straightforward way, so that the only equivalent of `window.onload` is `window.onload`.

Comment: This is interesting. But there `window.addEventListener("load", completed, false)` is fallback, it will never be triggered, because this listener will be detached by `completed` triggered by `DOMContentLoaded` which will happen before window load event.

Comment: @dfsq It will be triggered if [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_(event)) event is not supported. So basically it is *almost* the same.

Comment: the '$(function' and the '$(document).ready' both work fine however when the form is posted the field it relates to is coming through as not set even though a value is entered into it

Comment: @VisioN Hi. Have you any suggestions as to the following the '$(function' and the '$(document).ready' both work fine however when the form is posted the field it relates to is coming through as not set even though a value is entered into it All other fields come through fine

Comment: @VisioN Hi again If i use the $(window).load the field does not format as it should when data is entered but it does sent the data when posted but if i use either of '$(function' and the '$(document).ready the field does format correctly but does not send the data. Am very confused here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
      new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"AdddueBy",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"bDob",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"gDob",
        dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the folowing code worked `$(function' and the '$(document).ready` but with the JsDatePicker it was not sending the field data through to the next page.

It seems when you use JsDatePicker in a form. The form has to be Outside of the table in order to send the date field data through

Rather silly but that was the issue

:)